# How do I run globally installed Jupyter from within virtual environments?

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to run Jupyter notebooks with a globally installed version of Jupyter from within virtual environments (using `virtualenvwrapper`, because I want to manage versions of installed packages). And I do not what to use Anaconda.

The problem is when I run `jupyter notebook` from within the virtualenv, it cannot find the packages installed in the env, it only finds the packages installed globally.

How do I set up Jupyter to check for packages installed within the virtual environment instead of globally?

Here is what I get when I run `which python` and `which jupyter`:

globally:

```
which python  >>> /usr/local/bin/python
which jupyter >>> /usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

from within virtualenv:

```
which python  >>> /Users/brianclifton/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
which jupyter >>> /usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

running `jupyter notebook` from within the virtualenv:

```
which python  >>> /usr/local/bin/python
which jupyter >>> /usr/local/bin/jupyter
```

Also, here is my `.bash_profile`:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"

export PS1="\\[\[\e[38;5;94m\][\u] \[\e[38;5;240m\]\w:\[\e[m\] \$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

alias ls='ls -GFh'
alias pserv="python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
alias ipynb="jupyter notebook"

export WORKON_HOME=/Users/brianclifton/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=/Users/brianclifton/dev
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

alias branch='git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'

function frameworkpython {
   if [[ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
      PYTHONHOME=$VIRTUAL_ENV /usr/local/bin/python "$@"
   else
      /usr/local/bin/python "$@"
   fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to prefix your virutalenv's bin directory to your path. This way jupyter will find the virtualenv's libraries. You can do this by running `` export PATH:`which python`:$PATH `` after you activate your environment. It would be easy enough to alias.

However, a better solution may be to add this line to the [`postactivate` hook/script](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html). To find the location of this script do `ls $WORKON_HOME` after activate virtualenvwrapper and edit `$WORKON_HOME/<virtualenv_name>/bin/postactivate`.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution from [virtualenv doc](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

```
workon test
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --prefix=/usr/local --name test-kernel
```

Then your kernel should appear when you run jupyter from your other virtualenv, and all the packages installed in test would be available from it. Change prefix value according to the doc if you prefer a per-user installation instead of system-wide